# GtkWidget draw event fired mutliple times

Tags: c, events, gtk, gtk2, drawingarea

I have been scratching my head on Why is below code triggers on-draw callback three times as opposed to just once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace std;

void on_draw(){
    cout << "drawing"<<endl;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *drgArea;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  drgArea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
//  gtk_widget_set_redraw_on_allocate(drgArea, -1);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), drgArea);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  g_signal_connect(drgArea, "expose-event",
            G_CALLBACK(on_draw), NULL);
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess gtk+-2.xx? You should always add that when asking questions related to libraries that have a long version history with major differences between major versions.

Comment: i have another gtk+-3xx in my pc and when i switched my code to use that, callback count jumped to 4 !

Comment: In gtk3 you should use the "draw" signal, if you have further questions regarding that please open another question.

Comment: no i just tried it because you were suspicious about version numbers so i tried with another, definitely i used "draw" signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to your compositor/window manager.

Using cinnamon [2.0.14] shows `2` redraws when starting up the application (no matter if I use gtk3/3.10.6/"draw" or gtk2/2.24.22/"expose-event").

Comment: i thought like this, maybe those events like "realize" and "map" are routed as a normal expose events but when i added getchar() or sleep(1) just inside on_draw() function, number of callback reduce to just one!

Comment: this works properly on a different version of ubuntu, is there any way i can prevent multiple event queue on my development machine, thanks

Comment: Did you try to use a oldschool 2D non-composited windowmanager - I am not that familiar with the dirty details.

Comment: i think, i need to study on what is "non-composited windowmanager" thanks much